# Как реализовать правильный обход по матрице?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, матрицы, графы

Дело такое, что на учебе было дано задание. Задача кажется не из простых и до решения до сего момента не могу прийти.

***Задание:***  Дана матрица любого размера, каждая ячейка имеет значение, это и будет ее вес. Нам нужно двигаясь с правого верхнего угла, найти кратчайший путь на сумму, которую указывает пользователь. Ходить можно только по вертикали и горизонтали. Повторяющихся ходов не должно быть.

Посмотрел много информации на этот счет, может я ходил куда-то не туда смотреть в интернет, но все сошлось к графам, пересмотрел множество из них и остановился на Jump point search, но подстроить толком под свое решение и не сообразил.

*Хотелось бы услышать ваши варианты, а в лучшем случае решение.* Всем мир:)

Comment: Кратчайший путь откуда и куда?

Comment: куда придете, как я написал выше, каждая ячейка имеет значения с весом, начиная с правого угла потратить сумму, которую указал пользователь

Comment: Ну это как бы поиск в ширину называется...

Comment: @Akina так может предложите решение для данной задачи?

Comment: Предлагать решение вдрызг стандартной задачи, исследованной вдоль и поперёк, и имеющей решения на практически всех языках (ну, может, на брэйнфаке нету), и живых и мёртвых, да не по одному разу? не, я не настолько оптимист...

Comment: @Akina я вас услышал:)

Comment: Поиск в ширину применяется на невзвешенном графе. Тут скорее алгоритм Дейкстры нужен, но и он тоже в интернатах разжеван не по одному разу.

Comment: Укажите ограничения на размер матрицы. Может тут полный перебор пройдет :) В отличие от многоуважаемых комментаторов выше, я что-то не вижу здесь ни поиска в ширину, ни Дейкстры. Если рассматривать более общую задачу: найти в графе путь заданного веса с минимальным количеством ребер, то она вроде как NP-полная. Можно подумать в сторону ДП, пока поставил плюс вопросу.

Comment: @defaultlocale сразу не увидел, что написали, только сейчас отвечаю. Вариант с ДП звучит кстати неплохо, стоит посмотреть в эту сторону.